# Change Variable Name using Regular Expression

Tags: r, regex

I would appreciate your help.

I want to change variables' name in R. The name of variables is `"CACRAGE"`, `"CACRAA1"`, etc.
I want to remove `"AC"` in the middle, changing variables' name to `"CRAGE"`, `"CCRAA1"`.
I've tried the following expression and it does not work. Please help me!

```
gsub(pattern = '^CAC([A-Z]{3,}', replacement = '^C([A-Z]{3,}', colnames(milwaukee_test), fixed = TRUE)
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you remove AC in `CACRAA1` the result will be `CRAA1` right? In that case you can match `^CAC` and replace with `C` https://regex101.com/r/fy8Urk/1

Comment: It sounds like you want to change *strings*, not *variable names*, correct? Those two are very different …

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace "CAC" with "C" if it occurs at the beginning of the name?

```r
milwaukee_test <- data.frame(CACRAGE = 1:3, CACRAA1 = 2:4)

names(milwaukee_test) <- sub(pattern = '^CAC', "C", colnames(milwaukee_test))

milwaukee_test
#>   CRAGE CRAA1
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
gsub(pattern = '^CAC(?=[A-Z]{3})', replacement = 'C', colnames(milwaukee_test), perl = TRUE)
```

**Note**

- You need `perl = TRUE`, not `fixed = TRUE`, in order to use regex and lookarounds in it
- `^CAC(?=[A-Z]{3})` matches `CAC` at the start of string that is immediately followed with three uppercase ASCII letters.